# Centering a div contained inside a div relative to browser window when there's more content on the right

Tags: javascript, containers, horizontal-scrolling

I've been working on my new portfolio/website and decided to go for a design that is basically one big index page that scrolls horizontally to show the different sections and vertically to show the content of the sections. Both the container and the boxed inside have a fixed width. The container is positioned relative and the boxes inside are floated left and positioned relative.

My question now is - how do I make it so that, regardless of the size of the browser window the user has when opening the website and even when re-sizing, the first box appears centered horizontally in the browser window AND without revealing the content that is on its right (content to which the user can scroll horizontally using buttons)?

The inspiration for my website came from this website http://www.cosstores.com/
I've inspected the code and I believe they are doing it using JavaScript and negative margins; but my Javascript knowledge is quite basic and I don't really understand how these negative margins are implemented effectively.

Would appreciate it if someone could explain how it works for the COS website or even come up with an easier alternative a noobie like me could use.

Thank you and please feel free to ask me to post anything else you think could help understand the problem better!

Comment: You'll need to use javascript for this - checkout jQuery, its easy to learn. Then resize the content containers on page load - eg. `$(document).ready(function() { $('.content-container').width($(window).width()); })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really quite simple, don't you worry. [**See it in action!**](http://jsfiddle.net/HFfGC/7/)

You'll need to work on a grid system. (You *can* use different-sized columns, but it's simpler if everything's nice and square.) Create a container `div` and a bunch of child "box" `div`s in your **HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <br />
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box "></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Use `<br />` to start a new row. Otherwise, rows will extend infinitely. The container `div` is exactly the height and width of one box, so it will only show one box at a time. But you can scroll, obviously.

---

Annotated **CSS** below:

```
#container {
    font-size: 0; /* remove gaps between boxes */
    height: 400px; /* show one box at a time */
    margin: 0 auto; /* center horizontally */
    overflow: scroll; /* show scroll bars */
    width: 400px; /* show one box at a time */
    white-space: nowrap; /* let boxes continue horizontally until manually <br />'d */
}
.box {
    display: inline-block; /* stack up left to right */
    font-size: 14px; /* undo font-size from parent so you can actually see text */
    height: 400px; 
    vertical-align: top; /* line up tops of boxes within row */
    width: 400px;
}
```

---

Then, to scroll to a location with **Javascript**:

```
$("#container").animate({ scrollTop: 400, scrollLeft: 800 }, "slow"); //with animation
$("#container").scrollTop(400).scrollLeft(800); //without animation
```

You'll need [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to use that code. Well worth it, since it hides browser inconsistencies in scrolling with Javascript.

---

If you want to use the browser's scrollbars, you'll need to use the body as your container. It's trickier, because you don't have a specified width and height. There is no way to hide elements (for sure) from every user—some have truly massive screen resolutions.

Basically, add a margin on each box so you get some space around it. With some quick JS calculations, you can figure out the location of each box and center it on screen. [**See updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HFfGC/14/).

Here's the relevant JS for anyone interested:

```
$("#scroll").click(function() { scrollCenter("#target"); });
scrollCenter("#home", 0);

function scrollCenter(target, duration) {
    if (duration == undefined) duration = "slow";
    target = $(target);

    var offset = target.offset();
    var top = offset.top - ($(window).height() - target.height()) / 2;
    var left = offset.left - ($(window).width() - target.width()) / 2;

    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: top, scrollLeft: left }, duration);    
}
```

Run that OnDOMReady. The call to `scrollCenter("#home", 0)` forces the page to center the first box on load. You shouldn't even notice the jump.

Happy coding!

Comment: thanks you for this one! I was using a scrollTo, but I'll attempt this one and let you know how it worked

Comment: One small issue @primatology : u attempted the example and the box created is indeed centered, but it comes with it own set of scroll bars. Can't it be adjusted so that the scroll is done with the browser window scroll bars?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the jQuery plugin scrollTo

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Answer (score 0):

Centering a `div` tag on the screen is easy.  Set the `margin` property in it's css class to this:

```
margin:0px auto;
```

As for the rest of your question, this is a case for jQuery (in my opinion).  Take a look at this link:

http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/

And also google jQuery tutorials (you need to learn the framework first) and then, more specifically, "single-page sites" and "jQuery Paralax".

Good Luck!